# ld: framework not found Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to add a framework to my IOS project but when I build I always got the same message :

> ld: framework not found Pods
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried to remove my `Pods` directory and then run `pod install`
I open the `.xcworkspace` like it is written in the logs on the pod install, I clean the project on xcode and then try to build but it won't works..

My podfile looks like this :

```
xcodeproj '/Users/guillaume/project/Mobile/iOS/FoodPin/FoodPin.xcodeproj'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'SwiftHTTP', '~> 0.9.2'
```

My version of xcode is `6.3.1`

Thank you,

Comment: Did you check that `libpods.a` is in your "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" of your target ? And in your Build Phases too ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same error

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco I solved it, check my answer.

Comment: This [answer][1] solved my problem! 

Hope it helps


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31161871/1557663

Comment: @MárioCarvalho Thats just a longer and more beginner-friendly version of my answer x)

Comment: This is how I solved this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46358379/2024878

Comment: Best unser is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496314/1151916

Comment: For those using Codemagic make sure your Xcode version and your projects' global platform are the same, that is `Xcode version - 14.0` and `platform :ios, '14.0'`

Comment: Cocoapods probably is the worst garbage package manager ever created, you get all kinds of errors. Sometimes "framework not found" shows up only building to the simulator, but not on the device; sometimes the other way around. Piece of crap.

Answer (score 570, accepted):

In `Project Navigator` in the folder `Pods` I had a `Pods.framework` in there which was red. It was also present in `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`. I removed both references and the error disappeared.

**TL;DR**

Remove `Pods.framework` in:

- Folder named `Pods`
- `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`

Comment: I think I ended up with this problem after added use_frameworks! to my Podfile and subsequently commenting it out. Deleting the reference to Pods.framework fixed the issue.

Comment: @StephenT Yes I believe thats what I did too, first use `use_frameworks!` and then without and perhaps the `Pods.framework` wasn't deleted properly during `pod install`. Might be a bug in Cocoapods.

Comment: This is a good answer, doesn't affect the example app, it still running well

Comment: If this doesn't work, try using cocoapods-deintegrate. That just solved this problem for me.

Comment: This is a helpful quick solution, but note the answer below from @chris-trevarthen which provides the explanation and superior solution. It also is consistent with the current Firebase documentation (i.e. "open the ___.xcworkspace file")

Comment: Removing from *Linked Frameworks and Libraries* it worked for me :)

Comment: If you rename your project - then Cocoa pods doesn't automatically delete the framework file from linked library.  Might be a bug.. but seems like an edge case

Comment: After running pod install, I somehow ended up with a "Pods_<Project Name>".framework file in my Pods folder. Deleting this file, cleaning, and rebuilding removed this error for me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this error occurred for me after adding several more pods to my project, then deciding to roll back by shelving the changes in Git.

I have yet to resolve it using any of the methods I've found thus far – this thread included.

Comment: if this does not work, no way to undo your changes and all hell breaks loose on xcode..

Comment: Also, check the deployment target version with pod's platform version

Comment: I serached for pods and found the name of giving error pod-projectname.pod and removed it from dependencies... It worked thanks!

Answer (score 321):

This is usually caused by having the .xcodeproj file open instead of .xcworkspace.

When you run 'pod install' for the first time, it will create an .xcworkspace file, which includes your original .xcodeproj and a Pods project. You'll need to close your .xcodeproj and open the .xcworkspace instead.

This is a common issue when creating a project through Xcode's new project wizard - I often forget that I'm not in a workspace, which is required to get Cocoapods to link correctly.

Comment: When done in combination with the answer by Arbitur, this resolves the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: there is no .xcworkspace  file inside my project. what to do

Answer (score 161):

**Xcode 9, 10, 11, 11.5**

install https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate

```
pod deintegrate
```

then

```
pod install
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you. This got rid of an old reference to a renamed target that was causing this error.

Comment: Wow You saved my day! was stuck from yesterday and finally solved with Xcode 10.
Thanks!

Comment: This should be the correct answer, it's the safest approach. Don't do manual steps when using automated stuff like CocoaPods, unless it's a known bug that can't be fixed otherwise.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. But Elliott Davies answer works.

Comment: This was the only correct solution for me. Xcode 11.5 (11E608c). Thank you!

Answer (score 62):

I cleared this error by deleting the red `.framework` files that were located in a folder `Frameworks` in the `project navigator`. I think this also automatically deleted corresponding red entries in the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section of the `General` settings.

I have been cleaning / reinstalling pods in order to fix another issue.  Perhaps these red framework files and entries were just leftover from a previous pod install?

Comment: Yes! My issue was in Linked Frameworks and Libraries of the General settings and was difficult to find as it doesn't come up in a text search!

Comment: In my case the framework files weren't even red, but just grayed out. But deleting them seems to have fixed the problem!

Answer (score 58):

I had a similar issue as

```
framework not found Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension
```

It was resolved by removing the following. Go to **target** OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension > Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries and deleting **Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.framework**
[image: It should be empty here.]
Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. My particular situation is that I had an iOS target MyApp. Then I needed to create a second target and had MyAppFirst, MyAppSecond targets. Cocoapods was able to build what it needed (Pods_MyAppFirst, Pods_MyAppSecond) but it was also trying to link to Pods_MyApp which no longer existed. 

I want to point out that in the process of trying to fix I did throw away my workspace file and Pods folder to have them recreated from scratch when I performed a “pod -install” but that did not help.

Comment: @Sharukh Mastan Would you have any idea how to make this happen after a pod install? Every time I pod install, the `Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.framework ` comes back to haunt me in the linked frameworks and libraries of the `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` target.

Comment: @Sethmr Sadly, no. In my case, however, it doesn't always happen after a `pod install`, it's random.

Comment: @SharukhMastan My issue was opening the `*.xcodeproj/*.xcworkspace` over the `*.xcworkspace` with my vsts .yml automation script. I know better with a gui, but still getting used to the requirements in scripting land.

Comment: Thanks! I had to jump through some hoops to builds working on a new M1 mac. I was running out of patience by the time I got to this issue, so your solution really helped.

Comment: Thanks 01 Shahrukh! this is really helpful

Answer (score 42):

For who find this issue. I am using NativeScript and got the same error.

**That happen becouse I opened the file .xcodeproj, but we must open the project by the file .xcworkspace.**

Comment: This is indeed true

Answer (score 34):

This happened to me after updating my Podfile and doing a pod update.

For some reason, I had a "Pods_[ProjectName]".framework file appear under my project under 'Targets' > General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

Deleting this and then clean/rebuilding fixed the issue.

Comment: This happens when you switch project names and need to clear the old one out. +1

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't change project names, but added Swift to a long running Objective-C project.

Answer (score 16):

you should delete your project some file as this picture.

[image: your should delete the pods.framework and pods mark red files]

Answer (score 15):

I was getting this error because i renamed my project and change the name of project in pod file too but my project was referring to old name which was not there and causing this error . I get rid of this by

```
pod deintegrate
```

followed by

```
pod install
```

Comment: Yes! I had the same problem when downgrading version from 12.0 to 9.0.  The above worked after I'd modified the target version in my Podfile to match what was in the project.

Comment: Good Answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Just Remove your .framework from the list of "Your Project->General->Linked Framework & Libraries".

Comment: That was it, I had two after I renamed the project. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

It's happened to me because I changed the `Deployment Target` in `General` but forgot to change the `Deployment Target` in `Pods > General`.
[image: Change the deployment target]

Comment: Fixed it for me as well, Xcode 11.2/Cocoapods 1.8.4. Irritating that the error message bears no resemblance to the root cause...

Comment: Fixed it for me - didn't have idea that I need to change this in both places. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 11):

[Xcode 11.2.1]

For me it was different app target version in `Podfile`(`platform :ios, '11.0'`) and in Xcode project file [image: Xcode Deployment info].

It causing Archiving job fail in CI pipeline.

Matching both value fixed an issue! Hope this help anyone.

Comment: It did solve my problem too, I had extension and the extension deployment version was different. Thank you @Hemant

Comment: Same case, tried everything just this helped. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

This issue was driving me crazy as it suddenly happened without doing any changes to the project. I've tried all suggested solutions in this thread (and other related) and none of them solved the problem.

The only thing that differed from my other projects (which compiled fine), was that **this project name was containing an accent** (a french accent, "é"). I've renamed the project and all related files, and it finally worked !

Maybe this is related to updating to Xcode 10, because this project was working well before...

EDIT : it also seems to failed when using a project with `-` in project name…

Comment: You saved my life

Comment: Saved my life too!

Comment: Any solution besides renaming the project?

Comment: @anestis I don't think so. To quickly rename the project, I suggest commands from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48004237/4894980 which do a very great job!

Comment: My life is saved.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I can build it on devices and simulator but has the same errors when archiving. To solve it, I have to

- remove `Pods.framework`
- make sure `Pods-<project-name>.framework` is embedded

You will find the settings in  TARGETS-->Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

Comment: Could you check this out: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6203#issuecomment-261747869

Answer (score 6):

In my case, after comparing the difference between a branch I knew built correctly, I noticed this line in my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

I had inadvertently up'd my target version from 10 to 11 while my targets in Xcode remained set to 10. Reverting back to 10 solved my issue for me.

Ensure your target iOS versions are properly set.

Answer (score 5):

Step 1

> The first thing that you will need to do is remove the Podfile, Podfile.lock, the Pods folder, and the generated workspace.

Step 2

> Next, in the .xcodeproj, remove the references to the Pods.xcconfig files and the libPods.a file.

Step 3

> Within the Build Phases project tab, delete the Check Pods Manifest.lock section (open),Copy Pods Resources section (bottom) and Embed Pod Resources(bottom).

Step4

> Remove Pods.framework.

The only thing you may want to do is include some of the libraries that you were using before. You can do this by simply draging whatever folders where in the pods folders into your project (I prefer to put them into my Supporting Files folder).

It worked for me.

Comment: Step 3 worked in my case, step 3 -> cmd+alt+shift+k.

Answer (score 5):

Using Xcode 8.3 the accepted answer didn't work for me. I had tried many other solutions but @Elliott Davies answer is what fixed it for me. I'm adding a screenshot for clarity. For some reason, Xcode was trying to link previous podfile setups that no longer existed. All I had to do was delete the extra references and everything worked.[image: Screenshot of Xcode Linked Frameworks and Libraries]

Answer (score 5):

You're more than likely trying to get the pods to work into you project right? 
The only way to do so is by creating a separate project that uses CocoaPods.

Close all work-spaces that you are using.

Next, make sure you have your Podfile completely ready to go.

In the command line, wherever your file is, type the command:

```
pod deintegrate
```

Then, install your pod agian.

```
pod install or pod update
```

Now you can use your project's new workspace to develop from. Look for a file called .workspace. Use that file!

Here is a guide on using [CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html)

Comment: Only this one worked for me after struggle of 2 days with the error.

Answer (score 5):

This is the way i fix my problem. and it now work when i writing this answer:

Firstly, i try all the most fix way above,

**remove Pods_xxx.framework from the link libraries and framework in target's build phases is helpful, and the issue will disappear, but the coming problem is i can't import the Pods.framework anymore.**

And Then, i try to reinit the xcworkspace config, so that i can figure out the real problem. so i run

```
pod deintergate
```

and then install my pod again:

```
pod install
```

this work prefectly, but the problem is still in there, but i figure out the real problem is the Pods_xxx.framworks not be compiled succeed by cocoapods build script. I think this is the true way to fix the problem.

Finally, i try to edit my project's scheme:

[image: Pods scheme is not in edited]

and i add Pods scheme into manage:

[image]

and build this Pods.framework separately, and you will find the Pods.framework icon become truly again:

[image]

> and i think now you have fix your "framework not found Pods_xxxx.framework" problem
>   but actually i have another problem coming:

[image]

so i go to the build setting, and edit the `"Framework Search Path"` with `"${inherited}"`, 
**and now all the problems goes out, cheer!!!!:)**

[image]

Comment: Adding Pod target and building it actually showed what was wrong with the pod build. In our case this was swift version conflict. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't follow all the steps. I just added that `${inherited}` path, then did `Product->Clean Build Folder`, and that's it, now it builds without a hitch.

Comment: I used step ->  go to the build setting, and edit the "Framework Search Path" with "${inherited}", and now all the problems goes away,

Answer (score 5):

**I have resolved this issue.**

delete these three files.

1. Podfile.lock
2. Pods folder
3. .xcworkspace

Then open your project in terminal and run `pod deintegrate` command, and after then run `pod install` command

Answer (score 4):

After removing and updating pod I still had same issue.

I've found that previous developer put flag in '**Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags**' with Framework name (in my case -framework 'OGVKit') that made the issue.

After deleting that flag, project builds properly.

Comment: Thank you so much! You always have to keep an eye on stuff that are **bold** in Build Settings!

Answer (score 3):

Other thing that solved my problem is to go under Target -> Build Settings -> Other linker Flags and delete  the "-framework" and your framework "name".

It happened when i tried to remove a pod.

Answer (score 3):

in my case, my problem was the following: **ld: framework not found UserMessagingPlatform.xcframework**

for me, the solution was the following:

1. open a finder window and go to the **ios** folder
2. look for the following files:

Pods-**[YOUR PROJECT NAME]**.release.xcconfig

Pods-**[YOUR PROJECT NAME]**.debug.xcconfig

[image]

3. open those files and remove the following text: **-framework "UserMessagingPlatform.xcframework"** in both files

Comment: it doesn't crash if i do it, but.. everytime I do pod install then that line is added again and crashes. Also, what happens if I need this framework in the future? I think that is not the solution

Answer (score 2):

I did experience this problem because I did not set the `platform` correctly.

So in my macOS app I had the platform set to:

```
platform :ios
```

instead of

```
platform :osx
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, there was a reference to the library I removed on

> Targets > Build Settings > Runpath Search Paths

Removing the library from Podfile and updating it obviously didn't remove it, so I had to do it manually and now everything works.

Answer (score 2):

None of the previous answers pointed out the root problem in my situation.
So I hope this may be useful to someone else.

In my case I ended up having to edit my **podfile** at the root of my project. When I first created my podfile, swift static libraries were not supported.
So I had been using `use_frameworks!` in my podfile under each of my targets as such:

**BEFORE**

```
...
target 'targetName' do
   use_frameworks!
   pod 'podName', '~> 0.2'
end
```

**AFTER**

```
...
target 'targetName' do
   pod 'podName', '~> 0.2'
end
```

I removed `use_frameworks!` from my podfile which kept installing the frameworks every time I ran pod install. After removing this line, make sure to run `pod install` again and remove any of the red .framework references from your Frameworks folder in Xcode. (Though mine appeared differently as attached below.)

Image of [Removing .framework files that are no longer necessary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWVqI.png)

You can also read more about `use_framework!` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49469205/12269187).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after removing some pods from my project.
First I have used `pod deintegrate` after that `pod install` in the terminal but didn't work for me.
So I went to the second step inside my project `Build Setting` and on the `Other Linker Flags` option, I have found that the deleted frameworks are not removed so I removed them manually.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to remove two lines, 1. framework name; 2: "-framework"

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by selecting the project which downloaded from `CocoaPods` and built it, you can click Manage Schemes so that it can be appeared in Run bar. Then you can rebuild your project. Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

I tried every answer on here and none of them worked. I ended up getting it working by upping the deployment target from 10.0 to 11.0. I have no idea why that fixed it, but I suspect it has to do with upgrading to Xcode 10.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you suddenly open the wrong file of .xcodprj and you should open .xcworkspace

Comment: It is better to post such this as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was about changing the deployment target. I changed it to 9.0+ but changing it to 11.0+ worked.

Answer (score 1):

I used step ->  go to the build setting of your target, and edit the "Framework Search Path" with "${inherited}", and now problems goes for FBLPromises.framework not found.

Comment: Thank you ! This helped me solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case just deleting `Pods` folder and running `pod install` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

...and the correct answer is...

When you use pods (`Podfile` and `pod install`) it generates and tweaks some of the "Builds Settings" for you. However, sometimes you add something else, e.g.:

- You modify "Other linking flags" by adding a few more flags
- or you add extra frameworks manually, etc.

Hence, when you update `Podfile` so, that the generated project have to change the generated settings again, it skips them.. because you manually tweaked them.

For example, if you removed `use_frameworks!`, you dependencies should became binary, and they should not be added as frameworks, but if you modified "Other linking flags", it's not updated and keeps flags like `-framework CocoaAsyncSocket`. And when you build, obviously you don't have this framework anymore - .. and you have "Not found.." issue.

The solution is, to check which settings you tweaked and reset them to defaults. This will allow `pod install` to update them properly. But, running `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install` is not a right solution, because you might miss the manually added settings. Therefore, verify and saved somewhere the settings you modified, reset them (or use `pod deintegrate`), then `pod install` and then apply the manual settings back if they still make senses.

Answer (score 0):

If you opened .xcworkspace file and you still got the same error, delete all the contents of Pods directory and from command line write `pod install` to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the frameworks folder created after pod install or update

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by dragging `.framework` file to the **Linked Framework and Libraries**

Let say I was having this problem due to error `FIRAnalyticsConnector not found` and I just drag `FIRAnalyticsConnector.framwork` file to **Linked Framework and Libraries** and my problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Executable file inside .Framework like [image]

1. The executable file name should like this  without any extension.
2. Some frameworks showing like this  [image]
3. Using Terminal goto  .framework directory use below command
   lipo -create FrameworkName-x86_64 FrameworkName-armv7 FrameworkName-armv7s FrameworkName-i386 FrameworkName-arm64 -output FrameworkName

after creating single executable file delete this files [image]

Answer (score 0):

another great things is using this rule to disable the input & output paths of the CocoaPods script phases (Copy 
     Frameworks & Copy Resources):

```
 install! 'cocoapods',
        :disable_input_output_paths => true
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I created the workspace before installing the pods, so when I installed the pods, the workspace included my project only, add the Pods project to your workspace, clean and rebuild solved the issue in my case

Comment: Would be great if you could tell us HOW to add the Pods project to our workspace, the correct way?

Comment: close your project, do pod init and then pod install from the terminal, it would be created, you could just open the workspace then

Comment: Ok... What if I just do pod init, without closing the project?

Comment: Not sure if that would work, it will try to add the project (which is open by xcode) to a new workspace, even if it did, you still need to open the created workspace, not the project by itself

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that in my main project, the build setting `Build Active Architecture Only` was set to `NO`, and in the `Pods` project, it was set to `YES`.

After setting both to be the same, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
I faced this problem because I used non-English character in project name.

Problem solved when I changed the project name and run `install pod` again.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was

1. **delete** the *actually via pods removed and still error generating
   Framework* in Xcode **Target > Build Settings > Other linking flags** (in the section linking)
2. **Close Xcode** and after that run **pod update**
3. **Reopen Xcode** and then run **Product > Clean Build Folder** in the menu

After that my project is running and compiling again!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added the new pod entry in pod file using double quote **( pod "xposd" )** which was causing issue. **Try adding pod entry using single quotes** just like this **( pod 'xpod' )** in your pod file.

Answer (score 0):

`framework not found Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension`

In my case (Intel mac), setting the deployment target is the same (11.0) works for me:

1. pod file

[image: pod file]

2. Runner

[image: CleanShot 2022-12-20 at 22 40 23@2x]

3. One signal extension

[image: CleanShot 2022-12-20 at 22 41 40@2x]

Answer (score 0):

Just close the project and open file -> project.xcworkspace

Answer (score 0):

As shown in image, you should open `.xcworkspace` instead of `.xcodeproj`

Its basic issue but as a beginner we should know about this.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

1. pod init
2. close current xcode project
3. reopen xcode project with the xcworkspace suffix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQuNi.jpg)

Comment: In question is is already mentioned that they are are using .xcworkspace