# cocoapds ld: framework not found Pods_Target

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I can compile the target with debug configuration, but when change to release configuration, it failed with error:

```
    ld: framework not found Pods_MyTarget
```

this is the pod file:

```
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    platform :ios, '8.0'
    use_frameworks!


    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'SnapKit', '~> 0.15.0'
    pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 0.19'
    pod 'Nuke'
    pod 'Nuke-Alamofire-Plugin'
    pod 'RESideMenu', '~> 4.0.7'
    pod 'XCGLogger', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
    pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'
    pod 'UIColor_Hex_Swift', '~> 1.4'


    pod 'RxSwift', '~> 2.0.0-beta'
    pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 2.0.0-beta'
    pod 'RxBlocking', '~> 2.0.0-beta'
```

Comment: see this link may be helps with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139534/pod-error-in-xcode-id-framework-not-found-pods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I have to change the pod file to something like this:

```
link_with 'xxx'

target xxx do
    pod xxxxxx
end
```

and then delete some files generated by pod manually, seems pod cannot delete them, such as the xcconfig, framework, .etc
then run 'pod install'
it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this bug many a times. I do the below workaround, this may not be the right fix.

Go to Project settings and change "Build Active Architecture Only" to "NO".