# xcode - linker command failed with exit code 1 - build settings

Tags: ios, xcode, build, cocoapods

I'm using Xcode 7 and can't build successfully because of the following error:

```
ld: framework not found Pods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The error above is associated with the following file:

```
Ld /Users/(USERNAME)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/(PRODUCT NAME)-(RANDOM STRING)/Build/Intermediates/(PRODUCT NAME).build/USDev-iphonesimulator/(COMPANY NAME).build/Objects-normal/i386/(COMPANY NAME) normal i386
    cd /Users/(USERNAME)/Developer/(PRODUCT NAME)-ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

This error started occurring after merging multiple branches of code (each branch worked properly prior to the merge).  Can somebody tell me what is causing this error and how I can get past this problem?

**----- UPDATE -----**

Spending more time on this problem, I've noticed that the merged code works on my coworkers computers so the issue must be local.  Looking at the "Build Settings" (Go to the workspace file -> Build Settings (middle pane)), I noticed that the settings under the "Linking" section of "Build Settings is different between Xcode on my machine compared to my coworkers.  Not sure if this is the root issue, but does anybody know what I need to do in order to set the Linking settings?

Comment: did u open workspace file or project file ?

Comment: I used the workspace file and have tried product->clean as well as product - clean build.  Neither worked unfortunately.

Comment: go to pod settings and set build active architecture to NO

Comment: also check ur linked framework and libraries, if any file is red, remove them, and try to add them again

Comment: The frameworks and libraries are present. I think it's a problem with the settings under "linking" within "build settings". Updated question with details.

Comment: The accepted solution to the following worked for me:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139534/pod-error-in-xcode-id-framework-not-found-pods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an extra framework that I needed to remove:

1. Go to your .xcworkspace file
2. Click on the "General" tab in the Editor pane
3. Scroll down to the "Linked Framework and Libraries" section
4. Find the framework/library that the compiler is complaining about (in my case it was called "framework.Pods"

This problem stumped me for days...