# Flutter iOS pods not installing

Tags: ios, xcode, dart, flutter

I am trying to install alamofire pod file in my flutter project but I
got error like 'framework not found Alamofire'

I run pod install in my iOS folder its give error like 'framework not found Alamofire'

I have add pod file code

```
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
            'project '
            Runner ', {
            'Debug' =>: debug,
            'Profile' =>: release,
            'Release' =>: release,
            }

            def parse_KV_file(file, separator = '=')
            file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
            if !File.exists ? file_abs_path
            return [];
            end
            pods_ary = []
            skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
            File.foreach(file_abs_path) { | line |
                    next
                if skip_line_start_symbols.any ? { | symbol | line = ~/^\s*#{symbol}/
                }
                plugin = line.split(pattern = separator)
                if plugin.length == 2
                podname = plugin[0].strip()
                path = plugin[1].strip()
                podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
                pods_ary.push({: name => podname,
                    : path => podpath
                });
                else
                    puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
                end
            }
            return pods_ary
            end

            target 'Runner'
            do# use_frameworks!

                pod 'Alamofire'#
            Prepare
            symlinks folder.We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock# referring to absolute paths on developers ' machines.
            system('rm -rf .symlinks')
            system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

            # Flutter Pods
            generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
            if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty ?
                puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter packages get is executed first."
            end
            generated_xcode_build_settings.map { | p |
                    if p[: name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
                symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
                File.symlink(File.dirname(p[: path]), symlink)
                pod 'Flutter',: path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[: path]))

                end
            }

            #
            Plugin Pods
            plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
            plugin_pods.map { | p |
                    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[: name])
                File.symlink(p[: path], symlink)
                pod p[: name],: path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
            }

            end

            post_install do |installer |
                installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target |
                    target.build_configurations.each do |config |
                        config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
                end
                end
            end
```

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cmruivjpakthlvdshvwqbtebetrj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire'
ld: framework not found SwiftyJSON
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139534/pod-error-in-xcode-id-framework-not-found-pods

Comment: @Daljeet I try this but its not working

Comment: try removing this pod and add it again with pod install.

Answer (score -1):

Its solved I have just add following code https://github.com/mravn-google/flutter/blob/e0c73220a6f69d341ce436244212277d83bc189b/packages/flutter_tools/templates/cocoapods/Podfile-swift#L70-L73