# Error installing pods admob

Tags: ios, swift, admob, cocoapods

I tried to install a pods command, I got this error,

Ideas on how to fix it?

```
Ld /Users/ericdavila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LitHouse-evpsrrilluhozfglzlevnroqodjd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LitHouse.app/LitHouse normal x86_64
cd /Users/ericdavila/Documents/xCodeProjects/7.02
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
export PATH="/Users/ericdavila/Documents/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/ericdavila/Documents/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Users/ericdavila/Documents/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Users/ericdavila/Documents/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk -L/Users/ericdavila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LitHouse-evpsrrilluhozfglzlevnroqodjd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ericdavila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LitHouse-evpsrrilluhozfglzlevnroqodjd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ericdavila/Documents/xCodeProjects/7.02/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/ericdavila/Documents/xCodeProjects/7.02/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/ericdavila/Documents/xCodeProjects/7.02/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks -F/Users/ericdavila/Documents/xCodeProjects/7.02/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/ericdavila/Documents/xCodeProjects/7.02/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/ericdavila/Documents/xCodeProjects/7.02/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/ericdavila/Documents/xCodeProjects/7.02 -filelist /Users/ericdavila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LitHouse-evpsrrilluhozfglzlevnroqodjd/Build/Intermediates/LitHouse.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LitHouse.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LitHouse.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/ericdavila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LitHouse-evpsrrilluhozfglzlevnroqodjd/Build/Intermediates/LitHouse.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LitHouse.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LitHouse_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Users/ericdavila/Documents/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/ericdavila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LitHouse-evpsrrilluhozfglzlevnroqodjd/Build/Intermediates/LitHouse.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LitHouse.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LitHouse.swiftmodule -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework AdSupport -framework AddressBook -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreVideo -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework GLKit -framework GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework GoogleMobileAds -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleUtilities -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OpenGLES -framework SafariServices -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework SafariServices -framework CoreLocation -lstdc++.6 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AudioToolbox -lsqlite3 -framework Parse -framework Bolts -framework Pods_Lit_House -framework Pods_LitHouse -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ericdavila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LitHouse-evpsrrilluhozfglzlevnroqodjd/Build/Intermediates/LitHouse.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LitHouse.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LitHouse_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ericdavila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LitHouse-evpsrrilluhozfglzlevnroqodjd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LitHouse.app/LitHouse

ld: framework not found Pods_Lit_House
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: May helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865899/ld-framework-not-found-pods

Comment: I just deleted what was in red, I'll follow up if the problem persists

Comment: From `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` too?