# Xcode Workspace - Not finding imports from framework development pod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I've set up a workspace with two Swift projects in it: one a framework I'm developing, the other a demo app for the framework.

Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
workspace 'foo.xcworkspace'

target 'framework' do
    project 'framework.xcodeproj'
end

target :'demo' do
    project 'demo/demo.xcodeproj'
    pod 'framework', :path => 'framework.podspec'
end
```

the .podspec file looks like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name         = 'framework'
    s.authors      = { "foo author" }
    s.version      = '0.1.0'
    s.summary      = 'foo summary.'
    s.homepage     = 'foo homepage'
    s.platform     =  :ios, '9.0'
    s.license      = {
        :type => "Proprietary",
        :file => "LICENSE"
    }
    s.source       = {
        :git => 'https://url.to/foo.git',
        :tag => s.version.to_s
    }
    s.source_files = 'framework/framework/**/*.{swift,h,m}'
    s.requires_arc = true
    s.weak_framework = "XCTest"
    s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
        'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(inherited) "$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks"',
    }
end
```

After running `pod install`, Xcode/AppCode can still not see the classes from the framework project. So if I add a manual import to a class in the demo app and try to compile, it fails with:

> Error:(13, 21) use of undeclared type 'FooClass'

What do I have to do to properly have the demo app project see the classes from the framework project generated pod?

Comment: did you import the .h files inside your objc bridging header file? (If your pods are in objective c)

Comment: Sometimes you need to run a build once before the connections are properly made, did you try that?

Comment: The pod is in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue:

1. Make sure the min. required iOS is defined in **Podfile**, e.g.:

   platform :ios, '10.0'
2. Add any third-party pods also to the **podspec** file, e.g.:

   spec.dependency 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
   spec.dependency 'Serpent', '~> 1.0'
3. If doing `pod install` without the `use_frameworks!` it will mess up some things (see this answer: [ld: framework not found Pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865899/ld-framework-not-found-pods#31608019)). So in between I got these invalid Pod xconfigs that I had to delete and then do a clean and pod install.
4. Make sure to build the framework project at least once and then the demo source should find the import to the framework pod name!
5. Make sure that all classes are correctly added to their target, especially classes in the test target should not have been added to the app target accidentally.

After all is said and done, having worked with a multitude of IDEs and development technologies, Xcode and Cocoapods can only be summed up as one giant clusterf*** of an accident!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `inherit! :search_paths` on the demo target
This means they don't get their own copies of the pods but can see they exist via the header files.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
workspace 'foo.xcworkspace'

target :framework do
    project 'framework.xcodeproj'
end

target :demo do
    inherit! :search_paths
    project 'demo/demo.xcodeproj'
    pod 'framework', :path => 'framework.podspec'
end
```

untested but perhaps worth a shot

Comment: FYI: If I check Pods/Development Pods/fooframework the folder is empty. I think there should be something?!

Answer (score 0):

If you install a Cocoapod don't use the file with .xcodeproj to open your project anymore, but the newly created .workspace in the same folder.

Comment: Yes, I open the workspace, not the project. But that's not the cause of the problem.