# ld: framework not found FirebaseNanoPB

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, frameworks

I have a problem. My project does not compile.
This error always appears:

```
ld: framework not found FirebaseNanoPB
```

Im using this frameworks:

```
Using Firebase (5.7.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (5.1.1)
Using FirebaseAuth (5.0.3)
Using FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
Using FirebaseCore (5.1.2)
Using FirebaseFirestore (0.13.2)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (3.2.1)
Using FirebaseMessaging (3.1.1)
Using FirebaseStorage (3.0.1)
Using nanopb (0.3.8)
```

I get this from terminal.

It`s my pod file:

use_frameworks!

```
target ‘HomeAdvisor’ do
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'FirebaseInstanceID'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
    pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac'

    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
end
```

I`m using XCode 9.2.
Please, help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ld: framework not found Pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865899/ld-framework-not-found-pods)

Comment: @JadGhadry I solved the problem. I just downgraded from 5.7.0 to 5.4.0 version of Firebase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove below rows in Linker to fix this issue

```
-framework
"FirebaseNanoPB"
```

[image]

Comment: Saved my life, this was definitely it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be, you added `Other linker flags` manually.

Please remove other linker flags in your project, and reinstall pods call `pod install`.(re-construction other linker flags)