# ld: framework not found DTXProfiler

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to run a project in a new computer, but I have this error `framework not found DTXProfiler`
I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31608019/7686460) article, but I don't have any Pods.framework file nor `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`. I don't know what to do. I have also tried with `pod deintegrate + install`.

PS.

- I opened the .xcworkspace file, not the other one.
- Clean installed the project
- Deleted derived data a couple of times
- I don't even have `DTXProfiler` in my pods

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem...

Comment: @evanshabsove YES! I just posted my answer, if it helps you, don't doubt to leave an upvote c;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of having `homebrew` installed, just run.

```
brew tap wix/brew
brew cask install detox-instruments
```