# framework not found UserMessagingPlatform.xcframework in react native

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, mobile

I update my react native project after I encountered an error in xcode

there is no problem in android

Error:
[image]

My new package.json

```
"@react-native-firebase/admob": "^7.6.10",
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^7.6.9",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.7",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^9.3.2",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^8.4.12",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^7.9.1",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.9.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.2",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.11.1",
"dayjs": "^1.9.4",
"i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
"libphonenumber-js": "^1.8.5",
"lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.63.3",
```

My previous package.json

```
"@react-native-firebase/admob": "^7.6.9",
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^7.6.8",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.6",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^9.3.1",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^8.4.10",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^7.8.7",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.9.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.6",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3",
"dayjs": "^1.9.3",
"i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
"libphonenumber-js": "^1.8.4",
"lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
"react": "16.14.0",
"react-native": "0.63.3",
```

Comment: I had the same error, and I solved it by doing this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64687891/4984739

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally solved the problem. Need to update CocoPods.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

And then

```
pod install
```

Comment: +1000 thanks OP. I updated my cocoapods from 1.7.5 to 1.10.0 and install pods again for the project. Then it worked.

Comment: i updated cocoapods from 1.5.x to 1.10.0 and it works now!

Comment: I also tried it on Apple M1 Macbook Air. At first time it did not help, but later I tried again and it works. Also, it requires to enable Rosetta for  terminal app.

Comment: @Uğur please the missing part that peteroid added. After update, pod install is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem was cocoapods version.

And not only the old ones but the newest one also.

I upgraded cocoapods and the latest `1.10.1` version was installed.

Looks like it also has a problem. After a couple of hours and a couple of millions dead neuron cells I found out, that cocoapods **SHOULD BE DOWNGRADED TO** `1.10.0`

Hope this information will help others to save time.